# Set a custom Color (RGB) to a CellStyle using the SS model

Tags: java, apache-poi

On the [Manual](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#CustomColors) they show how to set a custom color using *HSSF* and *XSSF*. Our application needs to deal with both formats. Is it possible to assign custom colors sticking to the *SS* model?

The short code should clarify my problem:

```
final Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
final Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet();
final Row row = sheet.createRow(0);
final Cell cell = row.createCell(0);

// apply SS style here:
final CellStyle style = wb.createCellStyle();

// This one is not supported:
// style.setFillForegroundColor(128, 0, 128);
```

On the *HSSF* model we worked with Color Palettes, but those not supported by the SS model.
This code shows how we changed the `HSSFColor.GOLD` to a custom color.

```
final HSSFPalette palette = ((HSSFWorkbook) workbook).getCustomPalette();
palette.setColorAtIndex(HSSFColor.GOLD.index, (byte) 253, (byte) 205, (byte) 111);
```

With the SS model, *IndexColors* are introduced, but those are imutable.

Comment: I have a nasty feeling that the way the two formats deal with colours is just too different to be able to provide a common interface across them...